# advice and suggestions for table styles

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable, diagbox, dashrule

Hi there I'm working on my thesis and looking for the best way possible to present tabular data. I don't have much experience with `LaTex`, hence, I though to seek for some ideas and hits on how to do it.

To be fair, neither I'm dealing with very complex tables nor there are many of them in my work; however, sometimes they present some level of nesting and often it could be helpful to resort to `\diagbox` to have some clues on what the two indexes stand for.

Below is one example of such tables:
[image]

and code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{lcccccccccc}
\caption[\textbf{Some caption}]{\textbf{Some caption.}} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\diagbox{stats}{IDs}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{HG002} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{HG00514} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{HG00733} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{HG03492} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{NA19240} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
\cmidrule(lr){10-11}

&

\multicolumn{1}{c}{hap1} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{hap2} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{hap1} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{hap2} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{hap1} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{hap2} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{hap1} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{hap2} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{hap1} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{hap2} \\
\midrule

N50 & 45.94 & 45.02 & 20.35 & 20.12 & 45.73 & 43.81 & 17.85 & 20.16 & 12.15 & 13.00 \\
L50 & 20 & 18 & 41 & 44 & 23 & 23 & 50 & 45 & 77 & 64 \\
NG50\makebox[0pt][l]{$^{\ast}$} & 50.15 & 44.90 & 21.58 & 20.12 & 47.79 & 45.83 & 17.89 & 19.97 & 12.98 & 13.03 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{11}{l}{\footnotesize$^*$ NG50 metric is calculated considering a genome size of 3Gbp} \\
\bottomrule
\label{table:assemblies}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Now, what I learned so far is:

1. simple is best and avoid vertical lines
2. use the appropriate functions to draw table items and
3. stick as much as possible to more conventional approaches to draw tables

Based on this I'm pretty satisfied with the output, if not for the `\diagbox` not looking that "great" when not joining the horizontal lines drew with `\cmidrule`, and probably the very big gap between `\toprule` and `\cmidrule` below the samples' IDs which I guess is somehow unavoidable because of the `\diagbox`.

If anyone has any alternative way to present this data and some other similar one, any help is much appreciated. Granted, I kind of like the option of being able to break tables through pages *e.g.* `\longtable` and similar, I like the idea of having a `\diagbox` in the first cell as long as it looks nice — I'm also interested in other option in this regard.
Last but not least, it would be nice to have any form of dashed line integration as I've noticed `\longtable` is not very resilient to such edits.

Comment: [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) is a nice package for table formatting. Its documentation gives also good advice.

Comment: Please. Add. Missing. Lines. So. It. Will. Compile ...

Comment: @MS-SPO done. Apologies, they were mostly common packages, but still I'm aware I didn't provide a complete MWE, now it should compile!

Comment: Thank you. It‘s all about guessworking, telepathy, unnecessary packages etc. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you not use `\diagbox`; instead, just place the label "IDs" in a line above the 10 data columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\captionsetup{textfont=bf, skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{10}{S[table-format=2.2]} }
\caption[Some caption]{Some caption.}
\label{table:assemblies} \\
\toprule
Stats & \multicolumn{10}{c}{IDs} \\
\cmidrule{2-11}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{HG002} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{HG00514} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{HG00733} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{HG03492} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{NA19240} \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} \cmidrule{10-11}

& {hap1} & {hap2} & {hap1} & {hap2} & {hap1} & {hap2} & {hap1} & {hap2} & {hap1} & {hap2} \\
\midrule

N50 & 45.94 & 45.02 & 20.35 & 20.12 & 45.73 & 43.81 & 17.85 & 20.16 & 12.15 & 13.00 \\
L50 & 20    & 18    & 41    & 44    & 23    & 23    & 50    & 45    & 77    & 64    \\
NG50$^*$ 
    & 50.15 & 44.90 & 21.58 & 20.12 & 47.79 & 45.83 & 17.89 & 19.97 & 12.98 & 13.03 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{11}{l}{\footnotesize$^*$ NG50 metric is calculated considering a genome size of 3Gbp.} \\

\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: indeed this looks so much better. One thing I'm always in-between and not sure what to do is whether should I have the "Sample" at the same level with "IDs", or instead have half-way through the box more like a vertical centering in the cell. Let me know your opinion, thanks!

Comment: @Matteo - I know I've seen both options used in tables. Both are defensible.  Just choose whichever "look" you like better. I happen to like the option I used in my answer, in (large?) part because there can be no confusion as to what "Stats" refers to.

Comment: I see and that's a very good point, also I believe this option brings "Stats" to the same hierarchical level as "IDs" just from how the table is organized visually. The only props of the other option is that you have equal amount of withe space above and below the content of a cell. Still, I believe this is a negligible benefit compared to the way information is conveyed.